# Can't understand result of Monad >> application

Tags: haskell, monads

Operation >> description is the following:

> Sequentially compose two actions, discarding any value produced by the
>   first, like sequencing operators (such as the semicolon) in imperative
>   languages.

Here is the example which confuses me:

```
> ([1] ++ [2]) >> ([2] ++ [3])
[2,3,2,3]
```

I'm expecting the list [2,3] which would be result of right part of expression. How can result of [2,3,2,3] be explained?

Comment: `(>>)` discarded the _values_ `1` and `2`, but that doesn't mean that `x >> y === y`...

Comment: With simpler example I get what I had expected: [1] >> [2] results
[2]

Comment: Try it with different types to understand. E.g. `[1,2] >> ['a']`

Comment: @Scipio I didn't say it was impossible to find `x` and `y` such that `x >> y === y`, only that such a statement is not true for all `x` and `y`.

Comment: Like @pdexter says doing this with different values helps to understand the explanations below. E.g. this in ghci 
   ([1,2] :: [Int]) >> ["a","b"]
gives you
   ["a","b","a","b"]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(>>)` is by default defined as

```
a >> b = a >>= (\_ -> b)
```

so the value being ignored is an `a` in a given monadic value `m a`. The type of `>>=` specialised to list is:

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
```

`l >>= f` invokes `f` for each element of the list `l` to product a list of lists which is then concatenated.

e.g.

```
[1,2] >>= (\i -> [i, -i])
> [1,-1,2,-2]
```

Ignoring each input element and returning the value `[2,3]` will result in n copies of the list `[2,3]` for an input list of length `n`

e.g.

```
[1] >>= (\_ -> [2,3])
> [2,3]

[1,2] >>= (\_ -> [2,3])
> [2,3,2,3]
```

this second example is equivalent to `([1] ++ [2]) >> ([2] ++ [3])` in your question.

Answer (score 8):

A small complement to the answer by Lee:

```
([1] ++ [2]) >> ([2] ++ [3])
```

is equivalent to

```
([1] ++ [2]) >> ([2] ++ [3]) >>= \x -> return x
```

which is equivalent to

```
([1] ++ [2]) >>= \y -> ([2] ++ [3]) >>= \x -> return x
```

which is equivalent to

```
[ x | y <- [1]++[2] , x <- [2]++[3] ]
```

which is close to the imperative pseudocode

```
for y in [1]++[2]:
   for x in [2]++[3]:
      print x
```